# I want to transition for button but it is not working?

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions

```
.free-btn {
a {
    position: relative;
    .fbtn-bg {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size:20px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color:#000;
        padding:20px 85px;
        background: #f4f4f4;
        border-radius: 14px;
        z-index: 100;
        position: relative;
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        &:hover {
            top:10px;
            right: -10px;
            transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I want to transition for buttun but it is not working. Where is my mistake, can u help me guys?

Comment: add your html. lütfen

Comment: Problem solved, thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using right and left you should use translate().
the hover selector should look like this:

```
:hover {
  transform: translate(10px , 10px);
}
```

Comment: This is ideal. Also there's no need for the extra transition property in your hover effects. You only need that in the initial object.